# Looping two macros

Tags: lua

Morning!

I have a macro tied to a mouse button that repeats as long as I hold the button, once I let go it stops the macro. I can't figure out how to repeat them the way I need it. It has two pieces to it, block A and block B. When I first press the button I want block A to run, then block B.. however only block B is supposed to repeat after that until I let go. So A,B,B,B,B...

How do I do that? Block codes here:

BLOCK A

```
local function InterruptableSleep(ms)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
   while GetRunningTime() < tm do
      Sleep(5)
      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then return true end
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      repeat
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

 PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("5")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")

if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("R")

if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
         
               until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
    end
end
```

BLOCK B

```
local function InterruptableSleep(ms)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
   while GetRunningTime() < tm do
      Sleep(5)
      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then return true end
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      repeat

-- FIRST ROUND

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0")
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("5")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

-- SECOND ROUND

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0")
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

  if InterruptableSleep(500) then break end
PressAndReleaseKey("0") 
  if InterruptableSleep(400) then break end

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("5")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("2")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("4")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          if InterruptableSleep(math.random(110, 125)) then break end
         PressAndReleaseKey("3")
          if InterruptableSleep(900) then break end

      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
    end
end
```

Appreciate the help :3

Comment: Block B shoud be inside `repeat until` loop.  Block A should be before `repeat until` loop.

Comment: Hi Egor, would you mind helping me structure that? I can't get it to work >.> Sorry I'm not very good with LUA

Comment: There are 'first round' and 'second round' sections in block B.  Do you want to repeat first, second, second, second...?

Comment: Block B can repeat as a whole… so first, second, first, second etc. And allow me to ask; is it possible to fire of a different set of code, let me call it Block C, with a keyboard modifier? So do A,B,B,B.. and C if I hold alt (or whatever). Sorry if this is complex. You’ve been amazingly helpful, thank you!

Comment: Or instead, put a second macro on another key. Egor, you originally helped me make this fire and you had me bind BACK to G20. I have tried to make other G keys work, but I can't figure it out. If you can help me make G20 and G19 work simultaneously with different code for each, I don't need the alt modified

Comment: You should bind G19 to "back" (as you did for G20)

Comment: I'm not sure I explained that right. What I mean is use two different mouse buttons with two different scripts. So like MB4 to G20, MB2 to G19 or whatever.

Comment: If you never press G19 and G20 simultaneously then it is OK to bind "Back" to both G19 and G20.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      if not IsModifierPressed("ralt") then  -- Right Alt is not pressed
         repeat
            -----------
            insert here statements from inside repeat...until of block A 
            -----------
         until true
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
            repeat
               -----------
               insert here statements from inside repeat...until of block B
               -----------
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
         end
      else
         repeat
            -----------
            insert here statements from inside repeat...until of block C
            -----------
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I tried that, but am getting an error on my first sleep line in block A that shouldn't repeat. 
`if InterruptableSleep(math.random(100, 115)) then break end`
Can only get it to work if I add a repeat after the ralt modifier, but that messes the repeat of  Block C

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed.  Answer updated.